# IIS 7.5 Compression is not working when loading the page on a local computer

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, http-compression

If I try to access our website inside our servers using the remote desktop connection. YSlow and PageSpeed is reporting that our website are compressed. But If I try to access our website in my local computer, both the YSlow and PageSpeed reports that our site is not compressed.

I'm confused with it. I don't know anymore what configuration I needed to check to make sure compression is working.

Comment: this question is not really about programming so I'm not sure you can find the help you need here: I suggest moving your question to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)